# Using find to search and report files that have one but not two keywords inside

Tags: linux, awk, find

I'd like to use find to report files under the following conditions:

1. If the file contains the word "Serializable"
2. Then report the file if it does NOT contain the word
   "serialVersionUID"

Something like:

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec grep "Serializable" {} \; <magic stuff here> grep "serialVersionUID" {} \; -print
```

So am I smoking crack and would be better served by awk?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you. I gave it a try but perhaps there is a version problem?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick You could post that as an answer. Note that the `-a` is optional.

Comment: I agree. FYI. This is what I ended up using: `find . -name "*.java" -exec grep -E -q '(implements [a-zA-Z0-9]*[ ]*|[,]+[ ]+)Serializable' {} \; -a ! -exec grep -q "serialVersionUID" {} \; -a -print`

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293060/27616 shows that indeed you are better served by awk ^^ (Only 1 invocation of awk for the whole search, instead of multiple invocation of grep per files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-exec` operand of `find` evaluates to **true** if the command succeeds (i.e. returns zero) and **false** if it fails (returns nonzero), so you can use the success/failure of `grep` as part of the expression used by `find`.

Together with `find`'s `!` operand, which negates the following operand, you can search for files for which one grep command succeeds and another grep command fails:

```
find . -name "*.java" \
    -exec grep -q "Serializable" {} ";" -a \
    ! -exec grep -q "serialVersionUID" {} ";" -a -print
```

The `-q` option tells `grep` not to print out anything; we're only interested in its return value.

The `-a` operand isn't strictly required, but it doesn't slow things down and I like to use it when there's a possibility that the expression may grow even more complex and require `-o` or parentheses.

Comment: ... you execute up to 3 grep (of the whole file) **per** files ? ...  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/293060/27616 for a much better solution, with 1 invocation for the whole thing.

Comment: @OlivierDulac Up to two greps, each of which only reads up until the first match. The `-q` option makes grep exit right after the first match. But you're quite right - there are other utilities that can do this with just one pass through the file. I just suggested the minimal changes necessary to make the OP's `find`/`grep` command work.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick : sorry for the tone of my first comment ... And indeed, 2 not 3. I understand that you stayed close to the OP's attempt, but it usually is akin to a XYProblem : we should solve the need, not fix the how :)